# How to select large data from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have run into problem with selecting large data from SQL Server. I have a view with 200 columns and 200 000 rows. And I am using the view for Solr indexing.

I tried to select data with paging but it took a lot of time(more then 6 hours). Now i am selecting it without paging and it take 1 hour. But SQL Server takes a lot of memory.

What is the best method or approach to select large data in such situations from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the query you are using to show us how you are doing paging and filtering?

Comment: Here is code for paging `WITH SpecialTable AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DataId) AS 'RowNumber', *    
 FROM [dbo].[Data]
)
SELECT * 
FROM SpecialTable 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN {0} AND {1};`

Comment: Adapted your simple example to an indexed (in sql) table of 73.4 Million rows. Selecting first 1000 is sub second. Assuming the server isn't grossly under resourced you are likely suffering from index issues.

Comment: If you are running that query in management studio and returning 1 row and its taking 1 hour then your DBA needs to a good look at the database / server and see if its fit for purpose. There isn't anything wrong with it; if you are returning 200k rows to the user consider if its the best way to present it. If you are processing 200k rows can it be done in the database engine? If all those are No i would look at the network speed and work out how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

200k rows is not that much and definitely shouldn't take 6 hours, not even 1 hour.
I did not understant if the problem is on the actuall select or bringing the result to the application.
I would recomend running the select with NOLOCK to ignore blockings, maybe your table is beeing accessed by other processes when you are running the query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WITH(NOLOCK)
```

If the problem is on bringing the data to the application you'll need to provide mroe details on how you are doing it

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at your execution plan. Look at the properties in the very first operator and see if you're getting "Good Enough Plan Found" or a timeout. If it's the latter, you may have a very complicated view or you may be nesting views (a view calling a view). See what you can do to simplify the query in order to give the optimizer a chance to create a good execution plan.